Error resuming script execution with apps script after accepting user input

I'm running an apps script, which takes a Json string,  converts it to an object and adds some of the key values to a Google sheet. The following code has worked for some JSON strings. However with others, I get the error in the title. When I check the execution log , I see:

Suggesting that it doesn't restart after accepting the JSON string. Any idea why?
function importJsonToSheet() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Check if the active sheet is named "Sheet7"
  if (sheet.getName() === "sheet7") {
    // Prompt the user to input the JSON data
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var prompt = ui.prompt('Enter JSON data', 'Please paste your JSON data here:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var response = prompt.getResponseText();
    var button = prompt.getSelectedButton();
    
    // Check if the user clicked "OK"
    if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
      // Parse the JSON string into an object
      var jsonObject;
      try {
        jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
      } catch (e) {
        ui.alert("Invalid JSON format. Please enter valid JSON data.");
        return;
      }
      
        addRowFromObject(jsonObject.Single, sheet) ;


    } else {
      // If the user clicked "Cancel", display a message
      ui.alert("Operation canceled.");
    }
  } else {
    // If the active sheet is not named "Sheet7", display an alert
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("This script can only run on Sheet7. Please activate Sheet7.");
  }
}

EDIT:
function addRowFromObject(myObj, sheet) {

  Logger.log('in addRowFromObject');
  Logger.log(myObj);



  var headerRow = sheet.getFrozenRows(); // THIS SHOULD GET HEADER ROW 
  var headings = sheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRow - 1, 0, 1).getValues()[0];
  var newRow = [];

  headings.forEach(function (heading) {

    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(heading)) {
      newRow.push(myObj[heading])
    } else {
      newRow.push('');
    }


  });


  Logger.log(newRow);




  return newRow


}


addRowFromObject(obj.Single, sheet); undefined function call

If you are depending upon users providing  you with valid json that's probably not a reliable solution.

addRowFromObject(jsonObject.Single, sheet) ; this line seems to be the problem. Just to confirm my understanding, you're goal is to print/add the JSON data from user input to your Spreadsheet. Is that correct?

@cnavar , I've added the code for addRowFromObject above, if that helps

@user1592380 Yes, it really helps! I posted an answer with an updated code. Give it a try and let me know how it went.

Recommendation
I've made a few changes to your existing code and below is updated code that works as expected:
function importJsonToSheet() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Check if the active sheet is named "Sheet7"
  if (sheet.getName() === "sheet7") {
    // Prompt the user to input the JSON data
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var prompt = ui.prompt('Enter JSON data', 'Please paste your JSON data here:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var response = prompt.getResponseText();
    var button = prompt.getSelectedButton();
    
    // Check if the user clicked "OK"
    if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
      // Parse the JSON string into an object
      var jsonObject;
      try {
        jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
      } catch (e) {
        ui.alert("Invalid JSON format. Please enter valid JSON data.");
        return;
      }
      
        addRowFromObject(jsonObject, sheet) ;

    } else {
      // If the user clicked "Cancel", display a message
      ui.alert("Operation canceled.");
    }
  } else {
    // If the active sheet is not named "Sheet7", display an alert
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("This script can only run on Sheet7. Please activate Sheet7.");
  }
}


function addRowFromObject(myObj, sheet) {

  Logger.log('in addRowFromObject');
  Logger.log(myObj);

  var headerRow = sheet.getFrozenRows(); // THIS SHOULD GET HEADER ROW 
  var headings = sheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRow - 1, 0, 1).getValues()[0];
  var newRow = [];

  headings.forEach(function (heading) {

    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(heading)) {
      newRow.push(myObj[heading])
    } else {
      newRow.push('');
    }
  });

  Logger.log(newRow);
  sheet.appendRow(newRow);

  return newRow

}


I removed the .Single from this line addRowFromObject(jsonObject.Single, sheet) ; in importJsonToSheet function and added this line sheet.appendRow(newRow); in your addRowFromObject function to add the object values to sheet and here's the output from my sample sheet:

Reference

appendRow

Give this a try and let me know if it works!

thank you, but I need it to be jsonObject.Single to get the right subset of the object
